# How to stop a moving marker on Google map?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

these are my basic functions:

```
function autoRefresh(map) {
  var i;
  route = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    geodesic : true,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    editable: false,
    map:map
    });
  marker1=new google.maps.Marker({map:map,icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'});
  for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (coords)
    {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
      route.getPath().push(latlng);
      moveMarker(map, marker1, latlng);
    }, 300 * i, pathCoords[i]);
  }
}

function stop() {
  route.setMap(null);
  marker1.setMap(null);
  marker1 = [];
}
```

autoRefresh() is my function to start marker movement and stop() is to stop the movement. It works perfectly till I click start and stop buttons for first time. After clicking the stop button (before the marker completes its route) when I click start button, I want the marker to start from starting position as a new marker but it moves weirdly, joining the last position it was on and draws zigzag lines. Please help me, thanking you in advance.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/b3c45n6w/11/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker1, map, route;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: pathCoords[0].lat,
      lng: pathCoords[0].lng
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(8.893260000000001, 76.61427),
    map: map
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(8.52426, 76.93668000000001),
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
  });

  //autoRefresh(map);
}

function moveMarker(map, marker1, latlng) {
  marker1.setPosition(latlng);
  map.panTo(latlng);
}

function autoRefresh(map) {
  var i;
  route = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    editable: false,
    map: map
  });



  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
  });
  for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(coords) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
      route.getPath().push(latlng);
      moveMarker(map, marker1, latlng);
    }, 300 * i, pathCoords[i]);
  }
}

function stop() {
  route.setMap(null);
  marker1.setMap(null);
  marker1 = [];
}

var pathCoords = [{
   "lat": 8.893260000000001,
   "lng": 76.61427
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.894430000000002,
   "lng": 76.61418
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89484,
   "lng": 76.61416000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.894860000000001,
   "lng": 76.61383000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89488,
   "lng": 76.61375000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89563,
   "lng": 76.61370000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.896270000000001,
   "lng": 76.61366000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.896700000000001,
   "lng": 76.61364
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89671,
   "lng": 76.61351
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.896740000000001,
   "lng": 76.61312000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89675,
   "lng": 76.61307000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89677,
   "lng": 76.61305
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89729,
   "lng": 76.61303000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89755,
   "lng": 76.61311
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.898050000000001,
   "lng": 76.61311
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.898280000000002,
   "lng": 76.61321000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.899180000000001,
   "lng": 76.61289000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.900350000000001,
   "lng": 76.61396
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.900860000000002,
   "lng": 76.61467
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.90127,
   "lng": 76.61581000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.901710000000001,
   "lng": 76.61796000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.902190000000001,
   "lng": 76.61932
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.902370000000001,
   "lng": 76.62017
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.902370000000001,
   "lng": 76.62088
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.902460000000001,
   "lng": 76.6212
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.90313,
   "lng": 76.62217000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.903450000000001,
   "lng": 76.62240000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.903970000000001,
   "lng": 76.62272
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.90409,
   "lng": 76.62280000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.904,
   "lng": 76.62288000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.90342,
   "lng": 76.6233
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.902560000000001,
   "lng": 76.62386000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.90033,
   "lng": 76.62522000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.89601,
   "lng": 76.62777000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.88676,
   "lng": 76.63327000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.884450000000001,
   "lng": 76.63461000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.882610000000001,
   "lng": 76.63582000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.88089,
   "lng": 76.63711
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.87918,
   "lng": 76.63862
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.87785,
   "lng": 76.63936000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.875760000000001,
   "lng": 76.63996
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.87273,
   "lng": 76.64141000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.87067,
   "lng": 76.64251
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.869280000000002,
   "lng": 76.64336
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86805,
   "lng": 76.6447
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86782,
   "lng": 76.6451
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86677,
   "lng": 76.64822000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86645,
   "lng": 76.64933
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.866200000000001,
   "lng": 76.65092
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86546,
   "lng": 76.6533
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86508,
   "lng": 76.65451
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86495,
   "lng": 76.65667
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.864880000000001,
   "lng": 76.65962
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86519,
   "lng": 76.66080000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.866240000000001,
   "lng": 76.66343
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86646,
   "lng": 76.66454
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.866200000000001,
   "lng": 76.66933
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86569,
   "lng": 76.67323
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86522,
   "lng": 76.67823
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.863840000000001,
   "lng": 76.68872
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86359,
   "lng": 76.6907
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86364,
   "lng": 76.69282000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86317,
   "lng": 76.69574
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.863420000000001,
   "lng": 76.69850000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.8634,
   "lng": 76.69958000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.863050000000001,
   "lng": 76.70048000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.862350000000001,
   "lng": 76.70149
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.862020000000001,
   "lng": 76.70239000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86176,
   "lng": 76.70448
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86218,
   "lng": 76.70703
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.863180000000002,
   "lng": 76.70957
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.8636,
   "lng": 76.71115
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86382,
   "lng": 76.71257
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86383,
   "lng": 76.71368000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86354,
   "lng": 76.71509
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.863240000000001,
   "lng": 76.71595
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.86259,
   "lng": 76.71731000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.861540000000002,
   "lng": 76.71883000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.85947,
   "lng": 76.72208
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.85875,
   "lng": 76.72339000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.8573,
   "lng": 76.72554000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.85478,
   "lng": 76.72876000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.85397,
   "lng": 76.72962000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.8518,
   "lng": 76.73123000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.851220000000001,
   "lng": 76.73173000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.850200000000001,
   "lng": 76.73293000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.84966,
   "lng": 76.73342000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.848920000000001,
   "lng": 76.73382000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.84797,
   "lng": 76.73409000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.84509,
   "lng": 76.73453
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.843850000000002,
   "lng": 76.73492
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.84294,
   "lng": 76.73541
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.841140000000001,
   "lng": 76.73677
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.84003,
   "lng": 76.73747
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.838830000000002,
   "lng": 76.73848000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.836,
   "lng": 76.73998
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.835310000000002,
   "lng": 76.74063000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.83496,
   "lng": 76.74137
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.834480000000001,
   "lng": 76.74313000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.83385,
   "lng": 76.74406
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.832690000000001,
   "lng": 76.74528000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.83188,
   "lng": 76.74599
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.830480000000001,
   "lng": 76.7467
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.82831,
   "lng": 76.74775000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.82764,
   "lng": 76.74836
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.82665,
   "lng": 76.7493
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.82475,
   "lng": 76.7505
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.82245,
   "lng": 76.75188
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.82136,
   "lng": 76.75254000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.819880000000001,
   "lng": 76.75371000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.818140000000001,
   "lng": 76.75496000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.815700000000001,
   "lng": 76.75652000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.8125,
   "lng": 76.75867000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.809470000000001,
   "lng": 76.76091000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.806270000000001,
   "lng": 76.76203000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.804110000000001,
   "lng": 76.763
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.803410000000001,
   "lng": 76.76368000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.802990000000001,
   "lng": 76.76439
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.8024,
   "lng": 76.76629000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.80207,
   "lng": 76.76687000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.801540000000001,
   "lng": 76.76747
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.79983,
   "lng": 76.76870000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.799180000000002,
   "lng": 76.76894
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.798390000000001,
   "lng": 76.76903
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.79742,
   "lng": 76.76905000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.795710000000001,
   "lng": 76.76929000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.79439,
   "lng": 76.76955000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.79053,
   "lng": 76.77083
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.78954,
   "lng": 76.77144000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.788820000000001,
   "lng": 76.77241000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.78842,
   "lng": 76.77367000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.78814,
   "lng": 76.77574000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.78767,
   "lng": 76.77690000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.78735,
   "lng": 76.77735000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.78688,
   "lng": 76.77771000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.78307,
   "lng": 76.78025000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.779250000000001,
   "lng": 76.78346
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.77712,
   "lng": 76.78488
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.77275,
   "lng": 76.78745
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.770980000000002,
   "lng": 76.78802
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.76699,
   "lng": 76.78881000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.765640000000001,
   "lng": 76.78967
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.76401,
   "lng": 76.79095000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.763190000000002,
   "lng": 76.79128
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.76102,
   "lng": 76.79195
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.7558,
   "lng": 76.79388
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.75234,
   "lng": 76.79589
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.750900000000001,
   "lng": 76.79650000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.75009,
   "lng": 76.79726000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.748840000000001,
   "lng": 76.79895
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.747110000000001,
   "lng": 76.80017000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.74582,
   "lng": 76.80142000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.74407,
   "lng": 76.80305000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.74125,
   "lng": 76.80436
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.73728,
   "lng": 76.80730000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.73624,
   "lng": 76.80879
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.73544,
   "lng": 76.80953000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.732800000000001,
   "lng": 76.8109
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.731950000000001,
   "lng": 76.8113
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.730500000000001,
   "lng": 76.81166
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.72644,
   "lng": 76.81249000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.723980000000001,
   "lng": 76.81252
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.72197,
   "lng": 76.81271000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.720460000000001,
   "lng": 76.81268
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.71958,
   "lng": 76.81273
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.71719,
   "lng": 76.81297
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.71636,
   "lng": 76.81293000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.714080000000001,
   "lng": 76.81215
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.713080000000001,
   "lng": 76.81175
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.71254,
   "lng": 76.8117
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.71188,
   "lng": 76.81176
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.71118,
   "lng": 76.81200000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.70936,
   "lng": 76.81330000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.70716,
   "lng": 76.81486000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.70616,
   "lng": 76.81506
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.70514,
   "lng": 76.81497
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.70363,
   "lng": 76.81461
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.70148,
   "lng": 76.81371
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.70063,
   "lng": 76.81357000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.70003,
   "lng": 76.81360000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.698400000000001,
   "lng": 76.81366000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.698210000000001,
   "lng": 76.81378000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.69705,
   "lng": 76.81499000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.696520000000001,
   "lng": 76.81584000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.69635,
   "lng": 76.81654
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.695580000000001,
   "lng": 76.8182
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.69529,
   "lng": 76.81865
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.694780000000002,
   "lng": 76.81908
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.69355,
   "lng": 76.81999
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.6928,
   "lng": 76.82099000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.691880000000001,
   "lng": 76.82178
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.690430000000001,
   "lng": 76.82248000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.68914,
   "lng": 76.82319000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.68819,
   "lng": 76.82406
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.68773,
   "lng": 76.82423
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.68612,
   "lng": 76.82438
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.68462,
   "lng": 76.82435000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.68229,
   "lng": 76.82445000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.68044,
   "lng": 76.82475000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.67947,
   "lng": 76.8251
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.678650000000001,
   "lng": 76.82560000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.678180000000001,
   "lng": 76.82599
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.67652,
   "lng": 76.82787
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.67533,
   "lng": 76.82933000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.67463,
   "lng": 76.83056
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.6738,
   "lng": 76.83302
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.67337,
   "lng": 76.83368
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.67276,
   "lng": 76.83424000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.67102,
   "lng": 76.83500000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.669350000000001,
   "lng": 76.83574
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.6684,
   "lng": 76.83630000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.665890000000001,
   "lng": 76.83818000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.66487,
   "lng": 76.83893
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.66254,
   "lng": 76.83997000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.66042,
   "lng": 76.8408
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.65906,
   "lng": 76.84094
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.65737,
   "lng": 76.84088000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.655100000000001,
   "lng": 76.84037000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.654060000000001,
   "lng": 76.84041
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.65291,
   "lng": 76.84082000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.65094,
   "lng": 76.84149000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.647400000000001,
   "lng": 76.84214
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.64208,
   "lng": 76.84372
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.63718,
   "lng": 76.84567000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.633890000000001,
   "lng": 76.84642000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.63049,
   "lng": 76.84713
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.62597,
   "lng": 76.84825000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.62233,
   "lng": 76.84888000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.61796,
   "lng": 76.85015
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.61705,
   "lng": 76.85052
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.611970000000001,
   "lng": 76.85444000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.609100000000002,
   "lng": 76.85662
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.60847,
   "lng": 76.85691000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.60748,
   "lng": 76.85704000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.604790000000001,
   "lng": 76.85632000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.60331,
   "lng": 76.85583000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.601980000000001,
   "lng": 76.85521
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.60084,
   "lng": 76.85462000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.599530000000001,
   "lng": 76.85423
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.598180000000001,
   "lng": 76.85446
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.59272,
   "lng": 76.85616
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.58853,
   "lng": 76.85780000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.587850000000001,
   "lng": 76.85819000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.58651,
   "lng": 76.85957
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.58371,
   "lng": 76.86185
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.58211,
   "lng": 76.86330000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.57942,
   "lng": 76.86524
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.57592,
   "lng": 76.86807
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.57488,
   "lng": 76.86879
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.573540000000001,
   "lng": 76.86953000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.57169,
   "lng": 76.87060000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56986,
   "lng": 76.87212000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56779,
   "lng": 76.87364000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56587,
   "lng": 76.87492
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56545,
   "lng": 76.8755
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.565230000000001,
   "lng": 76.87642000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56508,
   "lng": 76.87809
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.5647,
   "lng": 76.88276
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56473,
   "lng": 76.88329
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56521,
   "lng": 76.88474000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56591,
   "lng": 76.88702
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.566840000000001,
   "lng": 76.88966
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.566930000000001,
   "lng": 76.89045
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56609,
   "lng": 76.89177000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.564670000000001,
   "lng": 76.89337
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56283,
   "lng": 76.89437000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56193,
   "lng": 76.89489
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.5616,
   "lng": 76.89528
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.561290000000001,
   "lng": 76.89592
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.560770000000002,
   "lng": 76.89757
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.5608,
   "lng": 76.89906
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.56107,
   "lng": 76.90019000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.560960000000001,
   "lng": 76.90051000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.560640000000001,
   "lng": 76.90077000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.560080000000001,
   "lng": 76.90137
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.559880000000001,
   "lng": 76.90159000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.55888,
   "lng": 76.90188
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.557310000000001,
   "lng": 76.90271000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.55607,
   "lng": 76.90337000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.55532,
   "lng": 76.90364000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.554450000000001,
   "lng": 76.90429
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.55367,
   "lng": 76.90523
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.552750000000001,
   "lng": 76.90672
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.55192,
   "lng": 76.90914000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.551060000000001,
   "lng": 76.91055
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.55096,
   "lng": 76.91157000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.55077,
   "lng": 76.91293
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.549750000000001,
   "lng": 76.91429000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.54897,
   "lng": 76.91604000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.54884,
   "lng": 76.91713
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.54833,
   "lng": 76.91862
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.548340000000001,
   "lng": 76.91954000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.548340000000001,
   "lng": 76.92013
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.548150000000001,
   "lng": 76.92067
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.54765,
   "lng": 76.92168000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.547320000000001,
   "lng": 76.92183
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.546460000000002,
   "lng": 76.92172000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.54588,
   "lng": 76.92167
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.545010000000001,
   "lng": 76.92194
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.54223,
   "lng": 76.92337
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.54024,
   "lng": 76.92455000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.539470000000001,
   "lng": 76.92527000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.53843,
   "lng": 76.92589000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.536340000000001,
   "lng": 76.92666000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.535070000000001,
   "lng": 76.92738
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.5333,
   "lng": 76.92876000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.53275,
   "lng": 76.92896
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.5325,
   "lng": 76.92898000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.530420000000001,
   "lng": 76.92887
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.530040000000001,
   "lng": 76.92898000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52973,
   "lng": 76.92966000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.529630000000001,
   "lng": 76.93037000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52961,
   "lng": 76.93189000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52964,
   "lng": 76.93216000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.529430000000001,
   "lng": 76.93264
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52898,
   "lng": 76.93319000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.5289,
   "lng": 76.93355000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.528920000000001,
   "lng": 76.93416
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52889,
   "lng": 76.93433
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.528680000000001,
   "lng": 76.93433
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52801,
   "lng": 76.93436000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.527470000000001,
   "lng": 76.93437
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52581,
   "lng": 76.93447
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52491,
   "lng": 76.93469
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52449,
   "lng": 76.93471000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.524170000000002,
   "lng": 76.93523
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52411,
   "lng": 76.93534000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52424,
   "lng": 76.93537
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.5244,
   "lng": 76.93548000000001
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.524370000000001,
   "lng": 76.9364
   },
   {
   "lat": 8.52426,
   "lng": 76.93668000000001
   }];

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<input onclick="autoRefresh(map);" type=button value="Start">
<input onclick="stop();" type=button value="Stop">
<br>
<br>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: can you put that in a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b3c45n6w/
It is working on my system but I don't know why I am not getting the output in fiddle

Comment: Everything works fine here, you should redo your fiddle a bit to get to the state where it doesn't work. I can't see any problems now

Comment: Click the start button and before the marker completes its path, click the stop button. And then click the start button again and see what happens?

Comment: You mean like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleMarkerAnimation.html)?

Comment: @geocodezip, unfortunately he doesn't want that. I'm on the solution right now. He didn't clear the timer and he 's always starting from the first position rather then starting the array from the  position where he stopped actually. Aside from that I'm amazed what you have produce on your site, that's unbelievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep references to all the timers you create and cancel them all.

```
var timers = [];
function autoRefresh(map) {
  var i;
  route = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            geodesic : true,
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            editable: false,
            map:map
        });



        marker1=new google.maps.Marker({map:map,icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'});
        for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
            var timerhandle = setTimeout(function (coords)
            {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
                route.getPath().push(latlng);
                moveMarker(map, marker1, latlng);
            }, 300 * i, pathCoords[i]);
            timers.push(timerhandle);
        }
    }

function stop() {
  for (var i=0; i< timers.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timers[i]);
  }
  route.setMap(null);
  marker1.setMap(null);
  marker1 = [];
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/b3c45n6w/12/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker1, map, route, timerhandle;
var timers = [];
function initialize() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
     center: {lat: pathCoords[0].lat, lng: pathCoords[0].lng},
     zoom: 13,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(24.94676383440351, 67.13702201843262),
   map:map});
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(24.94276562875255, 67.18474388122559), map:map,
   icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
   });

   //autoRefresh(map);
  }

  function moveMarker(map, marker1, latlng) {
   marker1.setPosition(latlng);
   map.panTo(latlng);
  }
  function autoRefresh(map) {
   var i;
   route = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    geodesic : true,
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    editable: false,
    map:map
   });
   
   

   marker1=new google.maps.Marker({map:map,icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'});
   for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
    var timerhandle = setTimeout(function (coords)
    {
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
     route.getPath().push(latlng);
     moveMarker(map, marker1, latlng);
    }, 300 * i, pathCoords[i]);
                timers.push(timerhandle);
   }
  }

  function stop() {
            for (var i=0; i< timers.length; i++) {
                clearTimeout(timers[i]);
            }
     route.setMap(null);
   marker1.setMap(null);
   marker1 = [];
  }

  var pathCoords = [
   {
   "lat": 24.94676383440351,
   "lng": 67.13702201843262
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.945829958568236,
   "lng": 67.13824510574341
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94567431190732,
   "lng": 67.13839530944824
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.946121795527365,
   "lng": 67.13893175125122
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.946744378729154,
   "lng": 67.13951110839844
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.947308592037547,
   "lng": 67.14011192321777
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94783389175996,
   "lng": 67.1405839920044
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.948417555490515,
   "lng": 67.14116334915161
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94902067177291,
   "lng": 67.14184999465942
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.949740516372685,
   "lng": 67.14257955551147
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94909849301358,
   "lng": 67.14345932006836
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.948631564832016,
   "lng": 67.14403867721558
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.948106268511754,
   "lng": 67.14472532272339
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94752260330603,
   "lng": 67.14545488357544
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.946783290074784,
   "lng": 67.14635610580444
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.945907781824943,
   "lng": 67.14740753173828
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.944993355453292,
   "lng": 67.14860916137695
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.943709255897694,
   "lng": 67.15015411376953
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.941763625005482,
   "lng": 67.15279340744019
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.940401665098086,
   "lng": 67.15451002120972
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.939309654225738,
   "lng": 67.15601205825806
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.939275604733375,
   "lng": 67.15608447790146
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.939239123123972,
   "lng": 67.1561998128891
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.939275604733375,
   "lng": 67.15641438961029
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.939331543180167,
   "lng": 67.15677112340927
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.939565025118608,
   "lng": 67.157261967659
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94012927130989,
   "lng": 67.15838849544525
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.940328702535293,
   "lng": 67.15898394584656
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.940338430879503,
   "lng": 67.15927362442017
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.940260604104388,
   "lng": 67.16037333011627
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.940231419051027,
   "lng": 67.1607381105423
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.940343295051314,
   "lng": 67.16156959533691
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94059623172093,
   "lng": 67.16286242008209
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.940868624476717,
   "lng": 67.164106965065
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.941213978712003,
   "lng": 67.16572701931
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94161283732836,
   "lng": 67.16765820980072
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.9421478895418,
   "lng": 67.17001855373383
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.942318132940574,
   "lng": 67.17079639434814
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.942770492828537,
   "lng": 67.17302799224854
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.943203394821786,
   "lng": 67.17518985271454
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94359251891071,
   "lng": 67.17712104320526
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.943864905041604,
   "lng": 67.17803835868835
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.944969035510336,
   "lng": 67.17934727668762
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94623853011741,
   "lng": 67.18083322048187
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.946885432298547,
   "lng": 67.1815949678421
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94726481695956,
   "lng": 67.1820455789566
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94776336553854,
   "lng": 67.18263298273087
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94821813736032,
   "lng": 67.1832150220871
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.949594602266778,
   "lng": 67.18494772911072
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.950115028453187,
   "lng": 67.18566656112671
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.949983706165003,
   "lng": 67.18631565570831
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.949993433746716,
   "lng": 67.18661069869995
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.95001775269762,
   "lng": 67.18688428401947
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94977942677173,
   "lng": 67.18697547912598
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.949623785101817,
   "lng": 67.18683063983917
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94943896036326,
   "lng": 67.18671262264252
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94925413534736,
   "lng": 67.18659996986389
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94814517942712,
   "lng": 67.18636393547058
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.946627644618534,
   "lng": 67.18611717224121
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94444858757967,
   "lng": 67.18583822250366
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.942609978219703,
   "lng": 67.18559145927429
   },
   {
   "lat": 24.94276562875255,
   "lng": 67.18474388122559
   }
  ];

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<input onclick="autoRefresh(map);" type=button value="Start">
<input onclick="stop();" type=button value="Stop">
<br>
<br>
<div id="map"></div>
```